# Maximizing a convex objective over distributions

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

I have a question in mind where say $V(x,F(x))$ is a value function with derivatives $h_{1},h_{2},h_{22},h_{12}>0$. Suppose we have control over some distribution $F(x)$ of a variable, and the constrained maximization problem is

$\underset{F}{\max}\int_{0}^{1}V[x,F(x)]dx$

s.t. $\int_{0}^{1}F(x)dx\leq c<1$

My intuition is that the optimal $F$ should put all mass on high enough $x$ because $V$ is convex and cross derivative is positive. Since $x\in[0,1]$, I think the optimal distribution is equal to

$F(x)=1_{[1-c\leq x\leq 1]}$ a.e.

Is there any way to prove or disprove my intuition? How can we show no other distributions give higher value? Thanks.